# Мне нужно проверить тип данных, если он соответствует , то выполнить определенную логику . Но тайпскрит ругается на условие. Почему?

Tags: typescript, angular

```
 public editDocument(editColumnsDocument: Document | [Document, IdDelete?]): void {
    if (typeof editColumnsDocument === '[Document, IdDelete?]')
```

Вот ошибка.
TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"[Document, IdDelete?]"' have no overlap.

Comment: Потому что typeof вернет вам стоку, которая будет '"string", "number", "bigint", "boolean", "symbol", "undefined", "object", "function"'. И она никогда не будет равна строке "[Document, IdDelete?]", что вполне очевидно. Думаю, вам стоит изменить способ проверки входных данных или типы входных данных. Чтобы получить какой-то ответ(совет), то стоит перефразировать вопрос и добавить больше контекста проблемы.

Comment: Ты прав, я просто не понял сразу. Можно функцию написать для проверки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public editDocument(editColumnsDocument: Document | [Document, (IdDelete | undefined)?]): void {
    if (Array.isArray(editColumnsDocument))
```

Проверяет является ли параметр массивом